# Login with IAuthorizationPolicy and UserNamePasswordValidator with header data?

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, principal

I have a WCF service where I use a custom UserNamePasswordValidator to validate user.

```
public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            LoginHelper loginHelper = new LoginHelper();
            loginHelper.ValidateUserRegularLogin(userName, password);
        }
```

When this is done the IAuthorizationPolicy.Evaluate is triggered and this is where I set the principal to a custom user context like this :

```
evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] = userContext;
```

The problem is that I need 2 things to get the proper usercontext and this is username and a value from the header.

I know that I can use a messageinspector to get the header data like this :

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            IntegrationHeader integrationHeader;
            LoginHandler loginHandler;
            UserContextOnService userContext = null;

            if (request.Headers.Action == null || request.Headers.Action.ToString().Length < 1)
                return null;

            foreach (var header in request.Headers)
            {
                if (header.Namespace == "ns" && header.Name == "SecurityToken")
                {

                    return null;
                }
            }

            throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown username or invalid password");
        }
```

But I need to get this information in the Evaluate method so I can make a proper login(set principal). Is it possible? And if so, how? What is the alternative?

PS. This will be done by call so no specific login method could be used.

Solved:

I ended up with this :

```
integrationHeader = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<IntegrationCertificateHeader>(header.Name, header.Namespace);
```

Comment: One dirty trick I can think of is in AfterReceiveRequest you extract values from header and set it on identity's claimset and then in Evaluate extract it from identity's claimset and use it however you want. I haven't tried it but I guess it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to access header data with this ?

```
WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers
```